# Put all elements into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I've looked around, but nothing seems to answer my question. I have a simple map, 5x5. It has 25 divs, labeled a1-e5, as shown here:

```
<div id='a1'></div>
<div id='a2'></div>
<div id='a3'></div>
<div id='a4'></div>
<div id='a5'></div>
```

and so on. I'm trying to run a function to assign each div a class. To do this, I'm trying to put all the divs into an array, but the array always turns up empty. This is what I'm trying:

```
var divs = [];
$('div').each(function() {
    divs.push($(this));
});
```

It's just not adding anything to the array. At all. Any ideas? Thanks in advance for any help!

Edit: The code is inside of a function, I just gave you a snippet of the function. Sorry for any confusion on that!

Edit 2: I want to assign each div a random class, which is why I wanted to use an array.

Comment: Where and when is the code running, and how are you determining the contents of the array afterwards?

Comment: When do you call that function? the code seems to be ok and it's working

Comment: Why do you need to add them to an array to assign  class?

Comment: Have you included jQuery JS reference

Comment: function to assign each  div a class --> `$('div').addClass("myClass");`

Comment: _I'm trying to run a function to assign each div a class._  if just this you want then some body has already answered it.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I call the function directly after I wrote it, and I'm not altering the array in any way after.

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn sorry this wasn't clearer, each div will be assigned a random class, not all the same one

Comment: @Kyle But _where_ and _when_ is the function and the call placed?  If it's before the content of the page, there won't (yet) be any `div` elements for it to find.

Comment: How about using .children() from jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/dqvf6uwh/

Comment: @JamesThorpe you're right, that was the problem. I had it before all of the content. Funny how the simplest things can slip our minds. Thanks for your help!

Comment: random class among a set of classes? what do you mean random class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('div').each(function(idx,div){
    $(div).addClass('div'+idx)
})
```

This will result in

```
<div id="a1" class="div0"></div>
<div id="a2" class="div1"></div>
<div id="a3" class="div2"></div>
<div id="a4" class="div3"></div>
<div id="a5" class="div4"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply do `addClass`?

**JS**

```
$('div').each(function(key) {       

    $(this).addClass("divCss"+$(this).prop("id").substr(1,1)[0]);
});
```

**CSS**

```
.divCss1
{
    background-color:red;
}
.divCss2
{
    background-color:green;
}
.divCss3
{
    background-color:yellow;
}
.divCss4
{
    background-color:blue;
}
.divCss5
{
    background-color:teal;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SukanyaHalder/bvmuLrrv/3/)

Answer (score 0):

the jquery selector will return an array of items, so

`$('div')` returns an array

`var myDivs = $('div'); // gives you an array`

Make sure you run your code after the div's have been rendered in the dom

i.e. inside a `$(function () {});`

Answer (score 0):

Simply doing

```
$('div').addClass("className");
```

will add the class to all 25 divs.

**EDIT** :

As per your comment, you can do something like this :

```
$('div').each(function() {    
    /*Other code here to determine which class will be added to which div*/
    $(this).addClass("className");
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear. I want to assign each div a random class, which is why I put them in an array